# Adding Extra Headers in CSV

Tags: powershell, header, export-to-csv

Input CSV:

```
CHeader1,CHeader2,CHeader3,CHeader4,CHeader5
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
b1,b2,b3,b4,b5
```

Output CSV:

```
PHeader1,PHeader2
CHeader1,CHeader2,CHeader5
a1,a2,a5
b1,b2,b5
```

Already tried

```
Import-Csv -Path .\before.csv |
    select CHeader1, CHeader2, CHeader5 |
    Export-Csv -Path .\after.csv
```

This produces the file without parent level headers.

Any suggestions to add parent level headers in first line of CSV followed by client headers and then the data?

Comment: I can't make sense out of your output CSV file.  Not as a CSV file, anyway.  If the first line is a header, with two field names,  what is the second line?  Is it the first data line?  It sure doesn't look like a data line.  Also,  it has three fields in it,  while the header only has two.  I strongly suggest that you are NOT writing a CSV file, and that it's confusing to call it a CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to create there is not actually a CSV, at least not in a way that the `*-Csv` cmdlets could handle. You can manually create it like this, though:

```
'PHeader1,PHeader2' | Set-Content '.\after.csv'
Import-Csv '.\before.csv' |
    Select-Object CHeader1, CHeader2, CHeader5 |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoType |
    Add-Content '.\after.csv'
```